# No logs when running WilfFly as service in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wildfly, ubuntu-18.04, wildfly-17

I have successfully installed WildFly 17 on Ubuntu, like in this article: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wildfly-on-ubuntu-18-04/

If I run from ./standalone.sh it is fine, however when I start with

systemctl start wildfly

I have no logs at all... Service status shows it is ok, but it is totally ignoring all my settings in standalone.xml, standalone.sh etc. There is no log created, that is main problem - nothing in default log folder (wf/standalone/log), nothing in the one I declared (/var/log/wf17).

No idea where to look for the reason anymore, service starts and I have no output. With ./standalone.sh it works perfectly, but I need to have it as service...

Answer (score 0):

This site is a copy of `$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/contrib/scripts/systemd/README`.  If you've installed this the way the docs say the logs will be in `/opt/wildfly/standalone/log` named `server.log`